# Error in concat1D: rank of tensors[23] must be the same as the rank of the rest

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensor

Tensorflow 1.12.0

I traned SSD_Mobilenet_V1_pnp model (pre-trained with COCO) with my dataset.

On phyton works - detect objects good

Convert to js.

In Browser Run with error:

```
tfjs@latest:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error in concat1D: rank of tensors[23] must be the same as the rank of the rest (1)

    at assert (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest:2:5660)

    at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest:2:60833

    at Array.forEach (native)

    at assertParamsConsistent (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest:2:60811)

    at concat_ (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest:2:223560)

    at concat (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest:2:68004)

    at executeOp$13 (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest:2:800253)

    at executeOp$16 (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest:2:804261)

    at p (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest:2:811525)

    at e.processStack (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest:2:811935)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the export command, the js code you used to predict ... ? Can you share your exported model ? Are you able to export the pre-trained model and use it in the browser ?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/tfjs/lsahMOlHCj8

Comment: Then, I ended up removing post processing from model. This link should give you an idea:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/coco-ssd#technical-details-for-advanced-users.

Comment: But I do not know how to do steps 2 and 3 (2.Used single class NonMaxSuppression instead of original multiple classes NonMaxSuppression for faster speed with similar accuracy.
3. Executes NonMaxSuppression operations on CPU backend instead of WebGL to avoid delays on the texture downloads.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same kind of issue in `tfjs-node` and this error might need you to follow https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/coco-ssd#technical-details-for-advanced-users

NB: all the examples are in TypeScript, but it is easy to translate to JavaScript.

I detail the 3 steps below

### 1. Remove the Postprocessing steps

you will need to remove post processing steps from exported model

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model \
                   --output_node_names='Postprocessor/ExpandDims_1,Postprocessor/Slice' \
                   --saved_model_tags=serve \
                   ./saved_model \
                   ./web_model
```

This should solve your `rank of tensors[23] must be the same as the rank of the rest (1)` error.

But now you do not have any postprocessing in your model, so you need to do it directly in your javascript code.

### 2. Used single class NonMaxSuppression

The idea is to keep only the "best" boxes, and do this filtering in js

First, you need to find the maxScores, see example code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/coco-ssd/src/index.ts#L168-L186)

Then you will need to use **NonMaxSuppression** to remove all non-max scores.

See the [example code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/coco-ssd/src/index.ts#L124-L129) and [documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#image.nonMaxSuppression)

### 3. Executes NonMaxSuppression operations on CPU backend

You will get examples in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/coco-ssd/src/index.ts#L121-L123) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/coco-ssd/src/index.ts#L135) using [setBackend](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#setBackend) function

Note: in order to free memory, you will need to [tf.dispose](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#dispose) and [tf.Tensor.dispose](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#tf.Tensor.dispose) the tensors before changing the backend